# In the sea or in the sky

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

In the sea or in the sky
Sometimes also in your eye.
Melancholy feels like me
But energy I have plenty.
Into me you have vanished
Out of me you're astonished

What am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it...   Blue

In the sea or in the sky

> Both are blue

Sometimes also in your eye.

> Eyes can be blue

Melancholy feels like me

> Feeling blue

But energy I have plenty.

> Blue energy is a type of energy 'osmatic power', or maybe related to blue light waves

Into me you have vanished

> "Into the blue" = vanished

Out of me you're astonished

> "Out of the blue" = astonished

Comment: Damn was it so easy? ^^'

Comment: 38 seconds - oof! We had slightly different explanations for the 'energy' line but everything else pretty much matches spot on - nice :)

Comment: Yes only reason I was first response is Stiv spent more time typing up a better formatted answer. I knew it'd be a race so I skimped on details : )  So give him the check!

Comment: Hum I kind of find your energy explanation better, so I already have you the check :/

Comment: Also should have said 'give them'. Apologize for presuming.

Comment: Not a problem - 'him' is correct for me, so no harm done :)

Answer (score 5):

You are:

> **BLUE**

*In the sea or in the sky*
*Sometimes also in your eye.*

> The sea and sky are often **blue** in colour, and **blue eyes** are common also (thanks to blue irises).

*Melancholy feels like me*

> '**Feeling blue**' is a synonym for feeling sad or melancholic.

*But energy I have plenty.*

> '**[Blue energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmotic_power)**' is the energy available from the difference in salt concentration between seawater and river water (Source: Wikipedia).

*Into me you have vanished*
*Out of me you're astonished*

> Something which has gone '**[into the blue](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/into+the+blue)**' has disappeared or *vanished*. Meanwhile, something that comes '**[out of the blue](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+the+blue)**' has arrived unexpectedly!

Comment: I didn't know about blue energy, but I guess it works too!